# select2 event fires twice in angular4

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

**Markup**

```
<select2 
         [data]="data"
         [width]="1024"
         [options]="options"
         [value]="selectedData"
         (valueChanged)="onTagChanged($event)">
</select2>
```

**Angular 4 Component**

```
onTagChanged(data: { value: string[] }): void {
    console.log(data);
    this.selectedData = data.value;
}
```

> event `valueChanged` fires twice, how can prevent it.

Comment: in what context?

Comment: @RahulSingh: onTagChanged funcation called twice while selecting any value from select2. console prints twice.

Comment: Try `onSelect` event instead `valueChanged`.

Comment: @AvneshShakya: that's not working.

Comment: @KetanAkbari Can you log the event? In my case I look for `event.isUserInput === true` the first event have this and the second not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
 onTagChanged(data: { value: string[] }): void {
    console.log(data);
    this.selectedData = data.value;
}
```

You are again changing the value i.e   this.selectedData, so value gets changed twice, once when you selected a value and once you manually changed the value. 
Since the value is bound to selectedData, you dont need to explicitly change it in abvove method.

```
[value]="selectedData"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be like

```
<select2 
         [data]="data"
         [width]="1024"
         [options]="options"
         (valueChanged)="onTagChanged($event)">
</select2>
```

**just remove** `[value]="selectedData"`